# How to generate N columns with printf

Tags: bash

I'm currently using:

```
printf "%14s  %14s  %14s  %14s  %14s %14s\n" $(cat NFE.txt)>prueba.txt
```

This reads a list in `NFE.txt` and generates 6 columns. I need to generate N columns where N is a variable.

Is there a simple way of saying something like:

```
printf "N*(%14s)\n" $(cat NFE.txt)>prueba.txt
```

Which generates the desire output?

Comment: what is in NFE.txt

Comment: is a file which contains something like:

text
text
text
.
.
.

Comment: So a single line ?

Answer (score 1):

```
# T1 is a white string with N blanks
T1=$(printf "%${N}s")

# Replace every blank in T with string %14s and assign to T2
T2="${T// /%14s }"
# Pay attention to that T2 contains a trailing blank.

# ${T2% } stands for T2 without a trailing blank
printf "${T2% }\n" $(cat NFE.txt)>prueba.txt
```

Comment: Is not working but is prolly my fault somehow.
I get in prueba.txt just a question mark...
the value of N used is:

N=$(grep -c "text" file)

Comment: "1" missing from T1. Sorry there is goes.
THX allot! I'm still having some question marks here and there but that can be handled

Answer (score 1):

You can do this although i don't know how robust it will be

```
 $(printf 'printf '; printf '%%14s%0.s' {1..6}; printf '\\n') $(<file)
                                           ^
                                   This is your variable number of strings
```

It prints out the command with the correct number of string and executes it in a subshell.

Input

```
10 20 30 40 50 1 0
1 3 45 6 78 9 4 3
123 4

5 4 8 4 2 4
```

Output

```
        10            20            30            40            50             1
         0             1             3            45             6            78
         9             4             3           123             4             5
         4             8             4             2             4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write this in pure bash, but then you could just use an existing language. For example:

```
printf "$(python -c 'print("%14s  "*6)')\n" $(<NFE.txt)
```

In pure bash, you could write, for example:

```
repeat() { (($1)) && printf "%s%s" "$2" "$(times $(($1-1)) "$2")"; }
```

and then use that in the printf:

```
printf "$(repeat 6 "%14s  ")\n" $(<NFE.txt)
```